# How do I print all the queries in Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, debugging

Is it possible to display all the query strings in Magento? I really like to see what queries are executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will catch **every** query, but most run through the query method `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` `query` method in

```
lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
```

With that in mind, you could temporarily add some debugging statements (to a copy you make in `app/code/local/Mage` to be safe)

```
public function query($sql, $bind = array())
{
    // connect to the database if needed
    $this->_connect();

    // is the $sql a Zend_Db_Select object?
    if ($sql instanceof Zend_Db_Select) {
        if (empty($bind)) {
            $bind = $sql->getBind();
        }

        $sql = $sql->assemble();
    }
    echo "{$sql}\n<br />\n";
    var_dump($bind);
```

If you need to catch them all, you'd be better off doing this at the MySQL level (which isn't always possible depending on your host/IT situation)

Comment: how do you call this function? when are Zend_Db_Select Objects available? what is a bind?

Answer (score 53):

In Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql

```
Magento 1.4 : lib/varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

set

```
protected $_debug               = true;
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
```

and (if nor already there) create the folder defined in

```
protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/sql.txt';
```

Give read / write permission

Comment: Unfortunately this will not log all the queries because the class and its query() method is not uses everywhere.

Answer (score 22):

Activate the Zend SQL Profiler with the following node in your local.xml

```
<resources>
 <default_setup>
  <connection>
   <profiler>1</profiler>
```

Then you can access the profiler somewhere in your code and retrieve a lot of informations about all executed queries:

```
$profiler = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->getProfiler();
```

To simply output all queries:

```
print_r($profiler->getQueryProfiles());
```

You can add these two lines at the end of `index.php` to see all queries at the bottom of each page. Be aware that this will break AJAX requests that return a JSON response, so you might consider logging the queries instead of printing them, with this code (again, add it at the end of `index.php`):

```
$profiler = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->getProfiler();
Mage::log(print_r($profiler->getQueryProfiles(), true), null, 'queries.log', true);
```

Then you will find all queries in `var/log/queries.log`

Don't forget to remove the lines again after you finished debugging!

Answer (score 6):

The queries will vary significantly depending on your activities. If you have some control over your MySQL server, try turning on query logging:

```
set global general_log = on
```

Then you can get the SQL log to see queries. As a word or warning, Magento tends to execute dozens of queries on every page load, and hundreds to save an object.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 5):

```
$collection->printLogQuery(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the MySQL logging will sure log all queries transactions. Here is how you can turn on the logging on.To turn on the logging to log to a file. Place the following in the my.cnf file or my.ini file if on windows, and restart MySQL.

```
log = /path/to/your/logfile.log
```

Then if you want to log to the table **mysql.general_log**, run these queries:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Run these if you want to log to the file:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE"; 
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```