# Magento Exception Error

Tags: sql, magento, zend-framework

after i made some changes in the system configuration. The last step of the checkout doesnt work anymore. It says: “There was an error processing your order.” In the exception the following errors:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '26-85' for key 2' in /home/www/web74/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/web74/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/www/web74/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/www/web74/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/www/web74/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#4 /home/www/web74/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#5 /home/www/web74/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#6 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('magentosales_or...', Array)
#7 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Order_Tax_Item))
#8 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Observer.php(144): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Tax_Model_Observer->salesEventOrderAfterSave(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Tax_Model_Observer), 'salesEventOrder...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/www/web74/html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#12 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#13 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Abstract.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#14 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2155): Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#15 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#16 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping.php(522): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#17 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php(495): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Multishipping->createOrders()
#18 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_MultishippingController->overviewPostAction()
#19 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('overviewPost')
#20 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/www/web74/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/www/web74/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/www/web74/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Thanks in Advance for Your Help

Comment: Its a bit hard to help you out without more information regarding the changes you made. Can you provide more info?

Comment: hi tim, please look on the comment of the answer. thx

Comment: ohh i found the error: i have set taxes twice, cheeses christ, how many changes ive made;) if anyone else has the same error:
(i havent found when i asked the question) 
[Stack Overflow - Magento-order-saving-error-integrity-constraint-violation](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/9687964/magento-order-saving-error-integrity-constraint-violation#answer-13704209)