# Magento Order Report issue

Tags: magento, report

I'm having a problem when generating an order report: the report shown on the table does ignore some datas. For example: in july, there were a lot of orders, almost everyday, but when I generate the report it only shows two days of the mounth with the correct values, all the other shows "No Records found for this period". Obviously this is not about applying "Empty Rows".

It is happening in Magento 1.7.0.2

I hope for any contribution.

Comment: Need more info. Try selecting only that date in the range?

Comment: SH, I do filtrate the report by an inicial and a final date. On the example I used, I chose the first day of July and the last day of the same month but the result, as I sad, does ignore the actual values of some dates between this period.

Comment: Probably, you have some filter in place. You would need to see the actual select call made to the Database to determine if this is the problem. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504931/how-do-i-print-all-the-queries-in-magento>