# Get - Debug SQL query - Magento

Tags: php, magento

How can i get the SQL query of this?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(4329)->getCategoryIds();
```

Comment: I think it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504931/how-do-i-print-all-the-queries-in-magento

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable the sql debugging in magento , open the file `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` in your favorite text editor. Down around line 86, you’ll see the following class variables:

```
    /*
     * Write SQL debug data to file
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_debug               = false;
    /**
     * Minimum query duration time to be logged
     *
     * @var unknown_type
     */
    protected $_logQueryTime        = 0.05; 
    /**
     * Log all queries (ignored minimum query duration time)
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_logAllQueries       = false;
    /**
     * Add to log call stack data (backtrace)
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_logCallStack        = false;
    /**
     * Path to SQL debug data log
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/sql.txt';
```

Change the following variables :

```
 protected $_debug               = true; //false;
```

And

```
 protected $_logAllQueries       = true; //false;.
```

This is all.After running app goto sql.txt you will see all the queries .

Comment: Will it not work if it's not my favorite editor? How does the computer know what's my favorite one? Stop hacking my brain! Need more foil! Ahh

Comment: Great Thank you!    On my system, Magento Enterprise 1.14.2, the output is located here:   var/debug/pdo_mysql.log.  See the $_debugFile variable.

Answer (score 1):

`echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(4329)->getCategoryIds()->getSelect();`

should work

Answer (score 0):

On Objects of Type Zend_Db_Select (eg Varien_DB_Select) you can call the Method assemble() to get the SQL-Query String.