# How to check all queries executed by a specific code in Magento

Tags: php, magento

To check all queries by a specific piece of code I am using:

1. Modify from protected to public the variable $_debug in Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
2. Do the same for $_logAllQueries
3. Add this before code executes:

   ```php
   $adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
   $adapter->_debug = true;
   $adapter->_logAllQueries = true;
   ```
4. Add this after the code

   ```php
   $adapter->_debug = false;
   $adapter->_logAllQueries = false;
   ```

   so your final code will look like this:

   ```php
   $adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
   $adapter->_debug = true;
   $adapter->_logAllQueries = true;

   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);

   $adapter->_debug = false;
   $adapter->_logAllQueries = false;
   ```

Is there any other more elegant solution?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25113/how-to-log-all-magento-sql

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension available for Magento which i am personally using from long time (works for Community as well as EE) :

https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug

This will let you
- Check all requests
- See all SQL queries executed for a request
- See all layout handles executed
- and many more

Comment: Hi, I am using magneto-debug, a forked patched version, while Madalin Oprea does not accept any pull requests from a while. Is good, but not exactly for a specific piece of code.

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variation of my answer at [How do I print all the queries in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504931/how-do-i-print-all-the-queries-in-magento?rq=1)

Instead of activating the profiler globally in `local.xml`, add these before and after the code you want to test:

```
$profiler = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->getProfiler();
$profiler->setEnabled(true);

// ...

Mage::log(print_r($profiler->getQueryProfiles(), true), null, 'queries.log', true);
$profiler->setEnabled(false);
```

Then you will find the queries in `var/log/queries.log`

Comment: Thank you, @fschmengler, this is what I was looking for!

Best,
R

Answer (score 0):

You may simply open the MySQL Log file and monitor the logged queries while requesting the page, If you are using Linux for example, use the command tail -F to view all the changes on the log file in a live way.

Try this for example on debian: `tail-F /var/log/mysql.log`